# No reaction to RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to display Textboxes according to checking radiobutton off in RadioButtonList , but no change is displaying.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 2:
            TextBox3.Visible = true;
            goto case 1;
        case 1:
            TextBox2.Visible = true;
            goto case 0;
        case 0:
            TextBox1.Visible = true;
            goto default;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `goto` statement you used?

Answer (score 0):

Check and make  AutoPostBack="True".